# writing a function that returns the frequency of a word in a string

Tags: scheme, racket

so for my code I need to write a function that returns the frequency of a word in a string.
So far I have the following code:

```
(define (num-occurs sym lst)
  (define (counter sym lst count)
    (cond ((null? lst) count)
          ((equal? (car lst) sym) (counter sym (cdr lst) (+ 1 count)))
          (else (counter sym (cdr lst) count))))
  (counter sym lst 0))

(define (remove-all elem lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (if (equal? elem (car lst))   
            (remove-all elem (cdr lst))
            (cons (car lst) (remove-all elem (cdr lst))))))

(define (word-frequencies str)
  (let ((lst (string->list str)))
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
          (append (list (cons (car lst) (num-occurs (car lst) lst)))
                  (word-frequencies (remove-all (car lst) (cdr lst)))))))
```

when I give it an input like: (word-frequencies "hi there person hi")

I get this error. 
string->list: contract violation
  expected: string?
  given: (#\i #\space #\t #\e #\r #\e #\space #\p #\e #\r #\s #\o #\n #\space #\i)

Help would be appreciated why it's doing this?
I want my final output to look like.

(( hi . 2) ( there . 1) ( person . 1))

Comment: Be aware that `string->list` returns a list of characters not symbols. So `(string->list "hi")` returns `'(#\h #\i)`.

Comment: do you know how I could make it directly from a string to a list? So it just becomes '(hi there person hi).

Comment: You could split the string and map `string->symbol` on the resulting list of strings, ie. `(map string->symbol (string-split "hi there person hi"))`.

Comment: @M.Maric see my answer. It should be straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I've learned is that you should test your assumptions in the interpreter:

```
> (string->list "hi")
'(#\h #\i)
```

`string->list` produces a list of characters, not a list of strings.
This breaks down when you later attempt to recurse over this character list.
(Even if `string->list` did produce a list of strings, the recursion would break since your function expects a string, not a list.)

Racket has many useful library functions, and the one you're looking for *does* exist.

`string-split` splits a string (on whitespace by default) into a list of strings.

```
> (string-split "hi there hi")
'("hi" "there" "hi")
```

There is also `group-by`, which groups a list into a list of lists.
(Look up these functions in the excellent manual.)
`group-by` needs something to group by. Let's use the strings themselves.

```
> (define id (lambda (x) x))
> (group-by id (string-split "hi there hi"))
'(("hi" "hi") ("there"))
```

This looks very useful.
We can also make use of a function that builds the pair of word and frequency:

```
> (define (frequency-pair strings) (cons (car strings) (length strings)))
> (frequency-pair '("hi" "hi"))
'("hi" . 2)
> (map frequency-pair (group-by id (string-split "hi there hi")))
'(("hi" . 2) ("there" . 1))
```

Putting it together:

```
(define (word-frequencies str)
  (define (id x) x) ; Group strings by their own value
  (define (frequency-pair strings) (cons (car strings) (length strings)))
  (map frequency-pair (group-by id (string-split str))))

> (word-frequencies " hi hello hi there over there")
'(("hi" . 2) ("hello" . 1) ("there" . 2) ("over" . 1))
```

Comment: group-by is not available in Guile 3.x and seems not generally available, thoguh

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error was because `string->list` function returned a list of characters. So if you try to do something like this:

```
(string->list "hi there person hi")
```

You would end up with `'(\#h \#i \#space \#t \#h \#e ...)` instead of `'(hi there person hi)`.

The simplest way is to compose a list of symbols from the strings by scanning the list of characters and detect when the current character (`car`) is a `#\space` (whitespace), and build each word string based on that. This is probably not the most efficient way, but it does the job.

```
(define (string-to-lat str)
  (let ([char-list (string->list str)])
    (let build-list ([s char-list] [l '()] [w ""])
      (cond ((null? s) l)
            ((null? (cdr s))
             (append l (list (string->symbol (string-append w (string (car s)))))))
            (else
             (if (char=? (car s) #\space)
                 (build-list (cdr s) (append l (list (string->symbol w))) "")
                 (build-list (cdr s) l (string-append w (string (car s))))))))))
```

`(string-to-lat "hi there person hi")` will return `'(hi there person hi)`.

**Here are the steps:**

1. Convert the string to a list of characters with `string->list`.
2. Build a recursive function `build-list`, binding the initial scoped variables to initial values.
3. The key part lies in the last `if` expression, which goes like this

   - "If a space is found, call `build-list` with the list of characters without the space, and updated `l` by appending `w` to it, and resetting the `w` to an empty string.
   - Otherwise, recur normally by appending `(string (car s))` to string `w`.

`w` is a word accumulator that helps build each word and convert it into a symbol and put it into the final list whenever a whitespace is found on the `s` char list.

With this, it should be straightforward to count the occurrence of each symbol in the resulting list.